# ffmpeg video encoding for mobile devices

Tags: video, mobile, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode the video file from f4v to mp4 for mobile devices and using 2 different ffmpeg versions with the same configuration files. Encoding goes ok for both files. The one that I convert using ffmpeg version N-32754-g936d4d4-Sherpya failing to play on my blackberry.
This is the command line that I'm using:

`ffmpeg.exe -i some.avs -vcodec libx264 -b 500k -r 24 -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -threads 0 -coder 0 -bf 0 -refs 1 -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -y test.mp4`

The vido playes ok when I convert it using FFmpeg version SVN-r13712
Could you give me some light on where the issue couls be?

Comment: This site is dedicated to programming questions. You question is more suited to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on which additional libs were compiled with the different versions of ffmpeg. check the configuration output when ffmpeg starts. You can simply start ffmpeg without any options on terminal and you should see the the configurations and can compare them.

Comment: Not sure what to do about it? Should I build the new version with the same libs that are in the old version and disable everything elase?

Comment: just compare them first and if they differ, then yes rebuild it with the same libs